# Small emulsified breakfast sausages in Dutch countries

Tags: sausages

Halo!

We are in the midst of our honeymoon, and are traveling from Amsterdam to Brugges to Paris. Upon our first breakfast in Amsterdam we were presented with small (about 1.5 to 2 inches in length, about .75 inches in diameter) sausages. They were a regular breakfast item in Amsterdam, and then again in Brugges.

They are very light in both color and flavor. If I had to guess, they contain a mixture of chicken meat and pork fat. The contents are definitely emulsified. They are in natural casings, or at least they certainly were in Amsterdam. As I said, they are served with breakfast. In Amsterdam the sausages were very dense so the casi g would brown and pop open, whereas in Brugges the casing was much less full, which provided a pillowy, soft texture.

Does anyone know what these sausages are called? I'd love to make them for myself when I get back to the US.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to guess that you are likely getting british or irish breakfast sausage.  The national dutch sausage, Frikandel, is minced, skinless, and not usually eaten at breakfast.  There is a perception amongst the dutch that Americans eat nothing but meat and fat in huge portions.

I did a semester abroad in the Netherlands.  For the first few days, the host family fed me eggs and sausages for breakfast.  I usually have some toast or cereal for breakfast.  So, after a couple days I asked them if this is what they had for breakfast every day.  My host mother said, "No, this is what we were told Americans have for breakfast everyday!"

After a chat, they said they were buying British breakfast sausages and eggs for me.  Their typical breakfast was a slice of bread, some cheese, and a very strongly flavored liverwurst.  My tastes were not as developed back then.  After two days of that I asked if there was any other breakfast choices. My host mother bought me suikerbrood.  It is a loaf of bread with sugar baked in it.  It was delicious!  I told them that I enjoyed this new breakfast very much.  This caused a lot of chortling for my two host siblings.  It turns out that suikerbrood is a small children's breakfast.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I do have to admit that the liverwurst I had in both Holland and the Flemish portion of Belgium was probably the best I've had in my entire life - it was simply incredible.

Also, does the suikerbrodje have a texture that makes it seem like it "melts in your mouth"? Like upon taking a bite, the initial texture of bread is felt, but where your teeth compress it it seems to melt in your mouth? I ask because we had a bread like that, and couldn't get over the strange but wonderful mouthfeel. It was served, you guessed it, at breakfast!

Comment: It is a very soft bread that contains lots of butter.  It is dotted with sugar cubes (or sometimes sugar nibs).  I still make it at home as it is one of my fondest food memories.

Comment: I would just like to point out that the Frikadel (or Frikandel, though that _used_ to be a spelling error :)) is not considered a sausage in the Netherlands (or at least by me). Usually it's eaten with French fries or as a quick snack, and you usually only find them in snackbars or frozen in  supermarkets. They go nice with beers etc since they're fried. If you really want to taste a good Dutch sausage try a "rookworst". Most people agree that the ones from a HEMA (they're everywhere) are best, but you can also get brand ones (I recommend "unox") from most supermarkets.

Answer (score 1):

There are no regular breakfast items in the Netherlands that are sausages of any kind - we don't eat those for breakfast. My guess is you were staying in places that wanted to cater to British/American breakfast guests, so they added sausages.

Also, 1.5-2 inch sausages are uncommon in the Netherlands. They could have been mini versions of '[knakworst](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knakworst)', often presented as a snack to go with drinks or at a childrens party - those resemble your description.

Knakworst:
[image]

Mini-versions, sold under fantasy names like 'mini-knakworst' or 'borrelworst':
[image]